# Transfer all products from one magento installation to other

Tags: magento-1.9, product, importexport

How can I **transfer** all **product** from one **magento installation** to another (both are 1.9).

I tried to export all products and then import them in other store, but it failed. No product is imported.

Please help and please explain the process.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Transferring products from one Magento installation to another is not that easy.

You will have to take many things into consideration and then you'll probably still fail.

1. First things first

If you are using 'Export/Import', you'll have to make sure that the columns `_product_websites` and `root_category` have values that correspond to your new server. If for  example your magento website was named **foo.com** on your old server and **bar.org** on your new server you have to change that accordingly in your csv. Same thing with the name of the Default Category.

If you are using **Dataflow** the columns are **store** and **websites**

2. Categories

If you are using Dataflow, even if you do create a new category structure in your new server that looks like your old server, export csv files (by default) have Category IDs and not Category Names. So... You;ll have to either be extremeley lucky or very cautious to have the same category name with the same category id.

3. Attribute Sets.

You need to have exactly the same attribute sets in your new server, populated with the exact same attributes. (see 4)

4. Attributes

All Attributes must be manually duplicated to  the dot, including values for options and so on.

5. Images

You'll have to copy the directory structure of your `[OLD SERVER]/media/catalog/product/` directory to [`NEW SERVER]/media/import/ directory`.

Then in the import csv, you have to make sure that `image`, `small_image` and `thumbnail` columns have values that correspond with the above mentioned structure. For example `/t/e/test_images.jpg`

6. Finally

Make sure the default languages (or the export locale on the old server and the import locale on the new server) are the same. If not things like Enabled/Disabled products Yes/No attributes will not be correctly imported.

That said, don't you get any errors while importing that you can post and help us help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a database dump and then remove any tables which are not related to products or categories e.g. customer tables, log tables, sales tables etc. and then import this modified database dump to your database.

But make sure to backup the old database in case something goes wrong.